# analytics.js events page flow

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics

On our site, we currently have a search box that has an auto-complete suggestion filter.  I've added an analytics event action when a user clicks on the suggestion, this is fine, however when the user clicks the suggestion, it takes them directly to the suggestions page.  I want to be able to track the page flow from the page that the event happens, to where the event takes them to.  so currently my code looks like this:

```
var gotoWindow = function(suggestion, datum){
  ga('send', 'event', 'predicted search', 'select', datum, 3);

  switch(datum){
    case 'jurisdictions':
      window.open(core.appurl+'jurisdiction/'+jurisdictionsLookup[suggestion.name]+'/'+getSlug(suggestion.name)+'/','_self');
    break;
  }
}
```

should I be including a virtual pageview within my GA code?

Answer (score 0):

User flow is tracked by page view check you analytics account left hand side

**Audience > User Flow**

Also if you are

current flow is like search page > suggestion page > result page

you need to add page view script to all page not event tracking

```
ga('send', 'pageview');
```